# windows 8 style API for ASP.NEt (websites)

Tags: asp.net

I've heard that Microsoft has unleashed a windows 8 style (previously known as metro) API for ASP.NET
Does anyone knows anything about it? What is it called? Where to get it from?
Unfortunately I don't have any link about that API. I've tried searching for it but didn't get any luck. 
I have found some JQuery APIs, but I'm asking about the one done by Microsoft itself. Is there any?

Comment: i think you are confused with Web API. there is plenty of information available about it online ( check http://www.asp.net/web-api ). Good Luck.

Comment: I know the Web API, I was hoping that there's a simple way of creating 
"metro look" without having to reinvent any wheel (if there's already an API for it)

Comment: No, there is no "Windows 8 style" for websites.  Even if Microsoft designed one, the compatibility would probably be horrible since they would design it primarily for IE, not Firefox, Chrome, mobile, etc.  You can make a "Windows 8 style" app using HTML and JavaScript, apparently.  That, they can do since it's on THEIR operating system.

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess I should have made it more clear: there isn't one by Microsoft.  The OP was asking about one developed by Microsoft.  This website doesn't discourage contributing to old topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was hoping that there's a simple way of creating "metro look" without having to reinvent any wheel (if there's already an API for it)

That's not called an API, that's ususally called a theme: a set of stylesheets and images.

I think you are looking for [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/). It's got little to do with Microsoft though.